# Spatial indexing of a point pattern in R

Tags: coordinate-system, point, r

I have a point pattern and a tessellation (grid) in R. Is there a way to spatially index each of my points? In other words, my tessellation grid has *n* quadrats, I would like to know for each of my points which of these *(1:n)* quadrats they are associated with. 
If not, is there another way to do so in R? 
Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you mean by "index" and "tessellation"? For instance, are you talking about identifying the row and column of a grid, or are you thinking of something like a [quadtree](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31236/how-can-i-generate-irregular-grid-containing-minimum-n-points/31879#31879)?

Comment: Hi @whuber, I would like to have the row/column of a grid. Right now, I have a 114 by 71 grid that I created using quadrats {spatstat}.

Comment: An example is given in the question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26189/recreating-a-lat-long-grid-using-a-specified-formula and I believe your question is asked (and answered) at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/superimpose-grid-on-points-then-aggregate-points-within-each-grid-cell. I found these by [searching our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bgrid%20%2brow%20%2bindex).  If you need even more information, please start by browsing through those search results.

Comment: answered here, please declare cross-postings if you must do it, it's a fairly basic courtesy https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-January/017222.html